# How to encourage developers to ask more suitable questions on UXSE

Tags: discussion, support

It might just be something I have picked up on a little bit more since I am looking at a lot of questions recently, but I seem to notice many people who are not new to the community but new to UXSE (judging from the 101 reputation points) that appear to be developers (from StackOverflow) or programmers (from Programming StackExchange) asking UX related questions.

It seems to be that the style and format of the questions that they are used to on their respective forums have been asked on UXSE, and it is a different job educating developers to ask design questions compared to educating designers to ask better design questions on UXSE.

I am wondering if there is anything specific that has been done in the past or planned for the future to try and address the different users groups, because the New Contributor takes care of the latter, but I don't think there's anything useful for people that have come from other StackExchange sites to ask UX related questions.